# SocketException: Socket is closed. during unit testing

Tags: java, sockets, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test my class.

The class is like

```
class Manager{
    class Handler extends Thread{
        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        public Handler(Socket s){
            socket = s;
            try{
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and have unit test code too, like

```
@Test
public void testHandler(){
    Socket s = mock(Socket.class);
    Handler h = Manager.new Handler(s);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String("Hello").getBytes());

    try {
    when(s.getInputStream()).thenReturn(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertNotNull(h.in);
}
```

But, I could see an error message.
Error was

```
time, myPackage.Manager$Handler <init>
serious: null
    java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at myPackage.Manager$Handler.<init>(Manager.java:70)
    at myPackage.Manager$SocketServerThread.run(Manager.java:249)
```

at the line

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Your Handler constructor should not contain a catch. It should declare the exception to be thrown. The object is of no use unless the reader can be constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already passed the `Socket` to your `Handler` before setting `when(s.getInputStream()).thenReturn(is);`.
**Try this**

```
@Test
public void testHandler(){
  Socket s = mock(Socket.class);
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(new String("Hello").getBytes());

  try {
    when(s.getInputStream()).thenReturn(is);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Handler h = Manager.new Handler(s);

  assertNotNull(h.in);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this line `in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));` threw an exception but `h.in` was not null and the assertion passed??? Can you give the exception stack trace???

Comment: Right. The same exception occurred, and assertion passed. The stack trace is in my question.

Comment: I am asking for the full stacktrace. Because, if it really threw an exception in the place you said, then `in` would still be null and the assertion `assertNotNull(h.in);` should have failed.

Comment: Ok, looking at the trace, it looks like the exception is not caused by the call from the unittest but during the call from `at myPackage.Manager$SocketServerThread.run(Manager.java:249)`. Check which Socket object you are passing from the above line.

Comment: Thank you for continuous comments. I'll check it :) Have a nice day!